# Client side processing with javascript vs server side with mod_perl

Tags: ajax, perl, mod-perl

I have a perl script that converts strings to different encodings, like base64, ASCII or hex (both ways). Now I am writing ajax front end for it, and my question is; if I want to automate the detection of the encoding of the string submitted, is it more efficient to perform regex search on the string submitted with javascript before I send it to the server, or is it faster to leave it for the perl script to figure out what type of string?

To clarify, I am asking which of these two is better:

1. String submitted
2. Javascript detects the encoding
3. AJAX submits encoding and the string to perl script
4. Perl script returns decoded string

or

1. String submitted
2. AJAX submits the string to perl script
3. Perl script detects encoding and returns decoded string

Is there a particular rule of thumb where this type of processing should be performed, and what do you think is better (meaning faster) implementation?

Comment: Well, the main rule of thumb is that you never know that your server side code will be called by the javascript on your page **only**, so it would probably make your service more robust and general purpose if it could determine the encoding itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **must** validate your data on the server.  Period.  Otherwise you'll be sailing off into uncharted waters as soon as some two-bit wannabe "hacker" passes you a base64 string and a tag claiming that your javascript thinks it's hex.

Given this, it's up to you whether you want to *also* detect encoding on the client side.  This has some potential benefits, since it allows you to not send data to the server at all if it's encoded in an invalid fashion or to tell the user what encoding was detected and allow them to correct it if it's an ambiguous case (e.g., hex digits are a subset of the base64 character set, so any hex string could potentially be base64).  Just remember that, if an encoding gets passed to the server by the client, the server **must** still sanity-check the received encoding specifier and be prepared to ignore it (or reject the request completely) if it's inappropriate for the corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the scale.

If there will be a LOT of client requests to do this, it's definitely "faster" to do it on the client side (e.g. in JS before the Ajax call), since putting it on the server side causes the server to process ALL those requests whch will compete for server's CPU resources, whereas client side you will only do one detection per client.

If you only anticipate very few concurrent requests, then doing it in Perl is probably marginally faster since Perl's regex implementation is likely better/faster than JavaScript (I don't have any stats to back this up, though) and presumably the server has better CPU.

But I would not really think that the server side margin would be terribly big considering the whole processing shouldn't take that long on either side, **so I'd advise to go with client-side checking since that (as per the first paragraph) scales better.**

If the performance difference between the two really matters to you a lot, you should actually implement both and benchmark under both the average anticipated and the maximum projected client loads.